# How do I find gaps in ranges of numbers?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has an id, as well as start/end values with represent a range of numbers. I am looking to find the first gap of a certain size (or larger) between existing ranges. For Example:

```
|   id  | start | end |
|-------|-------|-----|
| xz132 | 2     | 5   |
| fd754 | 9     | 12  |
| sb825 | 16    | 23  |
```

(EDIT: IDs are not incremental)

if I am looking for the first gap of size 1, it should return the range 1-1 as available.

if I'm looking for a gap of size 3, it should return range 6-8 as available.

if I'm looking for a gap of size 6, it should return either null to indicate no gaps, or 24-29 to indicate adding another record at the end of the table.

Comment: For each `start` value, check whether an `end` value exists such that `start < end < start + gap_size`. Joining the table with itself or using `exists()` will both work.

Comment: Where did 28 come from?

Comment: if you're looking for a gap size 3, shouldn't the result be 6-8, because you are trying to get the first occurrence?

Comment: @trincot Probably from the next, hidden row? :-)

Comment: I am not sure I understood correctly, are you looking for a gap size at least as large or exactly equal to the query parameter?

Comment: @trincot updated the question, I wrote the wrong numbers but also it could return null since it's the end of the table and not an actual gap. Either scenario works for my use case

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis >= the size of the gap.

Comment: @AngelaKay then I think my answer is ok, can you check and let us know how it goes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using variables:

```
select @end+1 start, start-1 end
from   (select * from ranges order by start) as base,
       (select @gap := 3, @end := 0) as init
where  if(@gap < start - @end, 1, if(@end := end, 0, 0))
limit  1;
```

Replace the number assigned to `@gap` with the desired gap size.

For `@gap := 1`, it returns (1, 1)
For `@gap := 3`, it returns (6, 8)
For `@gap := 4`, it returns no data

Comment: You should use another variable to indicate the gap you are looking for. Otherwise isnt clear if your query is for 1 or for 3?

Comment: As suggested: a variable added ;-)

Comment: Your solution is very similar to what i was doing. But for `@gap = 2` return same result as `@gap = 3` http://rextester.com/WDTO32790

Comment: For `@gap = 2` the result is `(6, 8)` since that is the first gap that is at least the required size. This is because OP wrote *" ... or larger ..."*

Comment: Yes, but looking at OP sintaxys looks like should be `{6,7}` but is easy to fix. with `SELECT @end+1 start, @end+@gap end`

Comment: That is a matter of interpretation, but indeed the OP can decide which way to go. This way however, you get more information: the actual size of the available gap (the requested gap size was already given).

Comment: I think we have a winner folks!

Comment: Congrats, I revised my answer as well, just in case you want something with substantially more characters (in case you want to write a report, for example :-) )

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE (t.end+1)-t.start >= gap LIMIT 1;
```

**Explanation**

**t** is the name of your table

To get the gap, you need to subtract the start from the end and add 1.

**gap** is the gap of your choosing

`LIMIT 1` will get you the first result.

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2515dc/1)

Comment: This seems to get the first record of that range size, instead of the gap between them. Would need an `ORDER BY` to get the first one as well

Comment: Well, from your question I assumed that you would know the gap before hand: "if I'm looking for a gap of size 3" ...as for the ORDER BY, its default ordering is by the ID primary key

Comment: ah ok, the reason I said the order by is that we're not using incremental IDs in the actual database so I needed one in my case but you're right, not necessary for regular IDs as in my sample case. As for the gap, I do know the size, but i'm looking for space BETWEEN the existing records. so numbers 9-12 are taken, I want it to return a range of numbers that are not taken.

Answer (score 0):

Took into account the fact that IDs may not be consecutive; I needed a trick to allow search before the first record as well, that's why I "insert" on the fly a dummy pseudo-record of zeros. That is, of course, provided that `ID >= 1`; otherwise you should use another value, or another trick :-). "3" should be a parameter.

[live demo](http://rextester.com/XCFXK59206)

```
select a.end+1 as RangeFrom, b.start-1 as RangeTo
from 
(select * from test union all select 0, 0, 0) a left join 
(select * from test order by start) b on 
     b.start = (select min(start) from test x where x.start > a.end)
where b.start - a.end - 1 >= 3
order by 1
limit 1;
```

Comment: I am looking for gaps between existing records to know where I can insert a new one, it appears that your answer returns the record that already exists. your example is looking for a gap of size 3 so it should return the gap between id #2 and #3 (13-15) as in my example

Comment: You are right, revising... (although I think it is straightforward to complete!)

Comment: But please explain something, you said your IDs are not incremental, but from your comment (find a gap so you want to know where you can insert a new one) I understand that once you order by `start`, then `id` need not be ordered accordingly. Is this correct? My (yet incomplete) approach is based on the condition that id1 < id2 <=> start1 < start2, which apparently is not correct.

Comment: You're right. That does add some complication not having incremental IDs, sorry about that. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this simple query :

```
select * from `test`.`test_1` as out1 where `to` 
< ( select min( `from`  ) from `test`.`test_1` as in1 where in1.`from`   
> out1.`to`  )+ XX;
```

you can play with XXX to get the gap you want and this gives you all of them, you can use "order by from" and then " limit 1 " to get the first one